# Mismatched delete no longer undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator, c++17

I noticed that the [C++ draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) as of [e51a2152](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/e51a2152599bce93d72b371590d03960f99f85e3) no longer includes the following wording:

> the behavior is undefined if the value supplied to `operator delete(void*)` in the standard library is not one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either `operator new(std::size_t)` or `operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library, and the behavior is undefined if the value supplied to `operator delete[](void*)` in the standard library is not one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either `operator new[](std::size_t)` or `operator new[](std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library.

Does this mean that code like

```
int * const p = new int[42];
delete p; // instead of delete[] p;
```

will no longer have undefined behavior, or am I missing something?

Comment: You're reading it wrong. It says that `delete` needs a pointer returned by `new` or `new(std::nothrow)`, and that `delete[]` needs a pointer returned by `new[]` or `new(std::nothrow)[]`. Just like it always have been.

Comment: It's a draft for good reason. Every compiler vendor knows it's Undefined Behavior, and will treat it as such. The Standard will say what those vendors think it should say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any event, that paragraph deals with allocation/deallocation functions. Mismatched `new`/`delete` expressions are handled in [[expr.delete]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.delete#2), which remains intact:

> In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the operand of
>   delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object
>   created by a previous *new-expression*, or a pointer to a subobject
>   ([intro.object]) representing a base class of such an object (Clause
>   [class.derived]). If not, the behavior is undefined. In the second
>   alternative (delete array), the value of the operand of delete may be
>   a null pointer value or a pointer value that resulted from a previous
>   array *new-expression*.<sup>82</sup> If not, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The wording has simply been moved into the description for `operator delete`:

> `[new.delete.single]/12:` Requires: `ptr` shall be a null pointer or its value shall represent the address of a block of memory allocated by an earlier call to a (possibly replaced) `operator new(std::size_t)` or `operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t)` which has not been invalidated by an intervening call to `operator delete`.

See [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/e51a2152599bce93d72b371590d03960f99f85e3#diff-9ad056ad00075480a9b6f87f89842dafR1820) for the change in the GitHub repo. There is similar wording for the array version. Nothing has changed semantically, it's just the way it's expressed in the standard.

Comment: Note that the standard specifies that the default implementation of `operator new[]` calls `operator new` and returns the result. So if - and that's a big if - nothing replaces the default implementation of the array forms, I think the wording can be read to allow calling `operator delete` on something returned by `operator new[]`.